# Error while deploying my application

Tags: spring, struts, liferay-6

FATAL ERROR STARTING UP STRUTS-SPRING INTEGRATION **********
Looks like the Spring listener was not configured for your web app! 
Nothing will work until WebApplicationContextUtils returns a valid ApplicationContext.
You might need to add the following to web.xml:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: Please provide your web.xml, cheers

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding...

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

To your web.xml?  The error seems pretty clear.

Comment: i found this link it's telling me that liferay 6.1 is missing listner in web.xml http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/15246978

Answer (score 1):

```
Looks like the Spring listener was not configured for your web app! Nothing will work until WebApplicationContextUtils returns a valid ApplicationContext. You might need to add the following to web.xml: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
```

It doesn't get any clearer than this.    Add a `ContextLoaderListener` to your `web.xml` to get the app context on startup.

What's your question?

Comment: i found this link it's telling me that liferay 6.1 is missing listner in web.xml http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/15246978

Comment: You don't need a link - you have a clear exception and two answers on SO telling you what to do.  Why don't you do what we're telling you?

Comment: in my web.xml there is already what you told me to add,so any ideas

Answer (score 0):

Actually is seems this is a new bug in the class

```
com.liferay.portal.tools.deploy.BaseDeployer
```

as of Liferay version 6.1.1 as the thread you pointed out yourself (http://liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/15246978) indicates at the end:
 
http://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-29103
So either you wait for the next release to fix this or you add a patched version of BaseDeployer to your classpath.

If you decide for the second alternative make sure to follow the idea behind this guides 
http://www.liferay.com/de/group/customer/kbase/-/knowledge_base/article/14079871
http://www.liferay.com/de/group/customer/kbase/-/knowledge_base/article/14079952

concerning the placement of the jar which contains the patched version of the class.
Otherwise you might get yourself into quite some classloading issues.

Anyway, before you get into action have a look at 
http://www.liferay.com/de/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/19126821
Someone created a Community Edition patch that resolves arround 60 issues including LPS-29103